# wildcard search s3 objects in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

is there any particular way by which I can search the s3 objects with millions of objects populated, get it by a identifier that's in the middle of the string name of the file.

for eg -> objects are -> [ xxx-123-yyy.mp4, qqq-345-rrr.png] I need to find those with *123* but when I use * in the prefix its just considered as a string and not wildcard

Comment: What are you using, console, CLI, something else?

Comment: aws-sdk ( npm )

Comment: S3 offers no API to perform a wildcard search, you must list all objects and filter them locally.  You can either use [list objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ListingKeysUsingAPIs.html), or setup a [S3 inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/storage-inventory.html) and download and process the report to speed things up with a large number of objects.

Comment: yes I am trying that only but actually it was taking a lot of time to do the same so was a bit confused as listing was pretty fast with truncation logic but then I also had to log it somewhere in a specified format, so it did not work for me then I changed the format a bit and used the same logic of listing the objects